# wrapping label text within horizontalgroup (LIBGDX)

Tags: libgdx

I would like to wrap a big text, which is a label embedded into a Horizontalgoup, which is embedded into a table.
To have some structure in the table and to be able to remove and add elements fast I am using HorizontalGroups in this table.

But wrapping doesn't work when Horizontalgroup is involved.

Can someone help me ?

My Code for testing:

```
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal(SkinManager.getSkin()));
Table table = new Table();
int size  = 40;
HorizontalGroup horizontalGroup = new HorizontalGroup();
Label bigtext = new Label("big text big text big text big text", skin);
bigtext.setWrap(true);
bigtext.setWidth(size);
horizontalGroup.addActor(bigtext);
horizontalGroup.setWidth(size);
table.add(horizontalGroup).width(size);
table.setPosition(400,400);
table.setWidth(size);
stage.addActor(table);
```

*** Update ***
I just also tested with the HorizontalGroup alone:
Wrapping doesn't work for me with the wrap methods of the group :

```
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal(SkinManager.getSkin()));
        int size  = 40;
        HorizontalGroup horizontalGroup = new HorizontalGroup();
        Label bigtext = new Label("big text big text big text big text big text big text big text big text", skin);
        bigtext.setWrap(true);
        bigtext.setWidth(size);
        horizontalGroup.addActor(bigtext);
        horizontalGroup.setWidth(size);
        horizontalGroup.setPosition(400,400);
        horizontalGroup.wrap(true);
        horizontalGroup.wrap();
        stage.addActor(horizontalGroup);
```

Comment: Does it work if you use a Table instead of the HorizontalGroup?